# Query returns null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hello I've got this query to get users by email, which is an unique field in the db.

However, when i want to get the data on it, it simply returns null.

Here's the code

```
    public function getUserByEmail($email)
    {

            $statement = "SELECT id_user,nome,email,permissao,activo FROM sys_users 
                          WHERE email=$email";

            try
            {

             $sth = $this->db->query($statement);
             $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
             $rcs_users = $sth->fetchAll();
             return $rcs_users;

            }
            catch(PDOException $e)
            {
                "DB Error".$e->getMessage();
            }

    }
```

And the respective function call

```
$user_rcs = $user->getUserByEmail($email);

    var_dump($user_rcs); //returns null




    $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $user_rcs->nome;
    $_SESSION['permissao'] = $user_rcs->permissao;
```

And then I get this error

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\inacesso\admin\modules\auth\authhandler.php on line 24
```

Glad if you could help me!

Comment: Watch out, you need to add quotes to your sql query strings.

Comment: My email address is "ptomblin@'; drop table sys_users;--"

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/php.html

Comment: So how do you recomend me to escape data? You just see a part of the script but I'm using mysql_real_escap_string on posted data (email,etc). Is there a better way using PDO?

Comment: Use a bound variable, as it shows in the link I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, seriously have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Secondly I would imagine the `email` column is a string. As such, you'll need to surround `$email` with quotes in your query (after having sanitized it *vigorously* of course...)

```
WHERE email='$email'
```

#### PDO version:

```
$pdo = new PDO(...);
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT id_user,nome,email,permissao,activo '.
                       'FROM   sys_users '.
                       'WHERE  email = ?');
$result = $query->execute(array($email));
```

Comment: Depends on perspective; I consider it _sanitized_ if SQL isn't going to have trouble accepting and parsing it. (Cleaned up from any injections or malformed input).

Comment: I usually do as such to Insert in the db. I'll use it this way from now on. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

Strings in SQL have to be quoted, so unless `$email` arrives in the function with `'` and `'` around it, the SQL will error.

But you shouldn't be building SQL by mashing together PHP strings anyway. Use PDO or mysqli_* with [bound parameters (and prepared statements)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/19068) and that will take care of quoting (and escaping) for you.

Comment: How can I use pure PDO to do as such? Can you give me an example?